# How to conditionally set base class in declaration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, t4

I have a modified T4 template that builds classes from my edmx and its working smoothly except for derived classes.

```
Product : BaseItem // works fine as do all top level classes

TranslatedProduct : Product : BaseItem  // dang
```

I'm confused about how and where I can conditionally set the T4 template to ignore : BaseItem in the case of a derived class - ie

```
TranslatedProduct : Product
```

For example:

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#><#=code.StringBefore(" : ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#> : BaseItem
```

In my head i imagined it like -

```
if(code.Escape(entity.BaseType).Equals(string.empty)
{
   <#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#> : BaseItem
}
else
{
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial      class <#=code.Escape(entity)#><#=code.StringBefore(" : ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>
}
```

But I receive syntax errors so I'd like to see if anyone else has tried this and if I'm on the right path

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The scripts you provided hard-code `: BaseItem` to always appear.  This seems broken.

The original code is:

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#><#=code.StringBefore(" : ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>
```

This uses a class defined in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude

The portions of the script between `<#= #>` tags are just C# expressions, and the strings returned by those expressions are inserted inline.

The `code.Escape` method will return either the type name (as a string) or an empty string.

The `code.StringBefore` will append the first string (`" : "`) before the second string (the base type name), but only if the second string isn't null or empty.

To do what you're trying to accomplish, you can use the same trick they use, but in reverse.  Unfortunately you can't use their existing class, because they don't have some sort of `AppendIfNotDefined` method.  So we'll just use a more complicated expression.

Instead of:

```
code.StringBefore(" : ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))
```

We'll write:

```
code.StringBefore(" : ",
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(code.Escape(entity.BaseType))
        ? "BaseItem"
        : code.Escape(entity.BaseType)
    )
```

Here's the whole line, all crammed together:

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#><#=code.StringBefore(" : ", string.IsNullOrEmpty(code.Escape(entity.BaseType)) ? "BaseItem" : code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply - That's fine, but what I'm after is the default behaviour. ie. Make all classes inherit BaseItem, unless it is a derived class. This line of code is the default behaviour of T4.

Comment: Let me clarify further - this default BaseClass is not part of the model - as it looks very different to the T4 generated classes. So while probably not the best solution, its an easy workaround

Comment: @MikeW: So, the T4 template parts that exist between `<#= #>` tags are simple C# expressions.  Do you know what `entity.BaseType` evaluates to for top-level types?  E.g., is it `null`?